# Min and Max Date in Material UI DatePicker in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a condition wherein if `access` value is 1 then there's no restriction in selecting dates. However if the value of `access` is not 1 then you can only select today. My problem is that I can't select other months even if the value of `access` is 1. I can only select from within the month. How can I fix this?

Please see my code here.

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
  minDate={access !== 1 ? new Date() : ""}
  maxDate={access !== 1 ? new Date() : ""}
  fullWidth
  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
  inputVariant="outlined"
  id="date-picker-dialog"
  label="Select Date"
  format="MM/dd/yyyy"
  clearable
  value={values.start_date}
  onChange={(val) => {
    setFieldValue("start_date", val);
  }}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  helperText={touched.start_date ? errors.start_date : ""}
  error={touched.start_date && Boolean(errors.start_date)}
  TextFieldComponent={TextFieldComponent}
/>;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `undefined` instead of empty string if you don't want to add min/max constraints.

```js
<KeyboardDatePicker
  minDate={!access ? firstDay : undefined}
  maxDate={!access ? lastDay : undefined}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64194577/min-and-max-date-in-material-ui-datepicker-in-react]

Comment: Thank you. Do you know formik too?

Comment: @Joseph I personally use [tag:react-hook-form]. You can always ask another question if you have any.

Comment: You can [chat with me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222484/nearhuscarl) in here for more info. @Joseph